# format two tables inside a figure

Tags: tables, formatting, wrapfigure

I have a figure that contains two tables, I would like to give format to them.

What would be the best option?

```
{\footnotesize\begin{figure} [h!tb]
\centering
\begin{tabular} {l }
\hline
\textcolor{sql}{double} N;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[] L;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[,] Q;\\
\textcolor{sql}{int} d;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[,]rho;\\
\textcolor{sql}{public} NLQ(\textcolor{sql}{int} dimension) \{ \\
~~d    = dimension;\\
~~N    = 0.0;\\
~~L    = new \textcolor{sql}{double}[d];\\
~~Q   = new \textcolor{sql}{double}[d, d];\\
\} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\begin{tabular} {l }
\hline
\textbf{in}:   $record$, $d$  \\
1 :$n$ += 1\\
2: \textcolor{sql}{For} i=0 to d\\
3: ~~~~$L_i$ += $record_i$\\
4: ~~~~\textcolor{sql}{For} j=0 to i\\
5: ~~~~~~~~$Q_{i,j}$=$Q_{j,i}$= $record_i$*$record_j$ \\
6:~~~~~\textcolor{sql}{End}\\
7:\textcolor{sql}{End}\\
\textbf{out:}  $n$, $L$, $Q$ \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{NLQ Definition  and Reader Function}
\label{fig:implementNLQ}
\end{figure}
}
```

[image]

maybe something like this

[image]

by the way I am using:

```
\definecolor{sql}{rgb}{0,0,2.55}
\definecolor{sqlC}{rgb}{0,0.44,0}
\definecolor{BRICKRED}{rgb}{0.57,0.0,0.0}
\definecolor{FORESTGREEN}{rgb}{0.0,0.34,0.0}
\definecolor{GOLDENROD}{rgb}{0.75,0.55,0.0}
\definecolor{VIOLET}{rgb}{.7,0.0,0.05}
\definecolor{MIDBLUE}{rgb}{0.08,0.08,1.28}
```

for the color

Comment: Why are you not using an algorithm package for displaying you algorithm? Then you won't have to do the line numbering and indention manually. Examples for such packages are `algorithmic`, `algorithm2e`and `algorithmicx`. See for example http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms.

Comment: Instead of `{\footnotesize\begin{figure}` do `\begin{figure}\footnotesize`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to David's suggestion, for the line between the two tabulars, you can use the `\vline` command. To make the tables the same height (so that the bottom `\hline` line up) you can simply add two empty lines by using `\\` twice.

```
\begin{figure} [h!tb]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}[t] {l }
\hline
\textcolor{sql}{double} N;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[] L;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[,] Q;\\
\textcolor{sql}{int} d;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[,]rho;\\
\textcolor{sql}{public} NLQ(\textcolor{sql}{int} dimension) \{ \\
~~d    = dimension;\\
~~N    = 0.0;\\
~~L    = new \textcolor{sql}{double}[d];\\
~~Q   = new \textcolor{sql}{double}[d, d];\\
\} \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\vline
\hspace{1pt}
\begin{tabular}[t] {l }
\hline
\textbf{in}:   $record$, $d$  \\
1 :$n$ += 1\\
2: \textcolor{sql}{For} i=0 to d\\
3: ~~~~$L_i$ += $record_i$\\
4: ~~~~\textcolor{sql}{For} j=0 to i\\
5: ~~~~~~~~$Q_{i,j}$=$Q_{j,i}$= $record_i$*$record_j$ \\
6:~~~~~\textcolor{sql}{End}\\
7:\textcolor{sql}{End}\\
\textbf{out:}  $n$, $L$, $Q$ \\
\\
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{NLQ Definition  and Reader Function}
\label{fig:implementNLQ}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd use nested tables that will allow automatic placement of the rules.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,array}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{sql}{rgb}{0,0,.55}

\newcommand{\+}[1][1]{\unskip\hspace{#1em}\ignorespaces}
\newcommand{\var}[1]{\textit{#1}}
\newcommand{\key}[1]{\text{#1}}
\newcommand{\peq}{\mathrel{{+}{=}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\footnotesize
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}l|l@{}}
\hline
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
\textcolor{sql}{double} $N$;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[\,] $L$;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[\,,\,] $Q$;\\
\textcolor{sql}{int} $d$;\\
\textcolor{sql}{double}[\,,\,] \var{rho};\\
\textcolor{sql}{public} NLQ(\textcolor{sql}{int} dimension) \{ \\
\+ \begin{tabular}{@{} >{$}r<{$} @{}>{${}}l<{$} @{}}
   d &= \key{dimension};\\
   N &= 0.0;\\
   L &= \key{new \textcolor{sql}{double}}[d];\\
   Q &= \key{new \textcolor{sql}{double}}[d, d];
   \end{tabular}\\
\}
\end{tabular}
&
\begin{tabular}[t]{l}
\textbf{in}:   \var{record}, $d$  \\
1: $n \peq 1$\\
2: \textcolor{sql}{For} $i=0$ to $d$\\
3: \+ $L_i \peq \var{record}_i$\\
4: \+ \textcolor{sql}{For} $j=0$ to $i$\\
5: \+[2] $Q_{i,j}=Q_{j,i}=\var{record}_i * \var{record}_j$ \\
6: \+ \textcolor{sql}{End}\\
7: \textcolor{sql}{End}\\
\textbf{out:}  $n$, $L$, $Q$
\end{tabular}
\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{NLQ Definition  and Reader Function}
\label{fig:implementNLQ}
\end{figure} 
\end{document}
```

Note how math is properly segregated to give optimal spacing (and also uniform appearance to the symbols).

The setting of your `sql` color is dubious, as the values in an `rgb` specification are normalized to 1 as a maximum, so you're actually declaring pure blue, so I've changed it.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tables are vertically centred by default, change

```
\begin{tabular} {l }
```

to

```
\begin{tabular}[t] {l }
```

and they will align on their top line (although a tabular may not be the most convenient structure for laying out code fragments).